# jquery getting element name - prop('name') or attr('name')

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get element name by jquery -

please check the following example code: (or http://jsbin.com/usujeq/2/watch)

```
<div name = "foo1">
  <div name = "foo2">
    <div name = "foo3">
      <div name = "foo4">
        <button id = "clickme" type="button">
</div></div></div></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#clickme').click( function() {
  $(this).parents().each( function() {
     console.log($(this).prop('name'));
  });
});
</script>
```

if I click `clickme`, it should go up all over the DOM from `<div name="foo4">` to `<html>` and log their names.

expected result is :

```
foo4
foo3
foo2
foo1
undefined
undefined
```

`prop('name')` returns undefined while `attr('name')` gives expected names.
what is wrong with `prop('name')` in above code?

Comment: @MikeHogan no, from all `<div>`s

Comment: That's simply not valid HTML5: http://html5.validator.nu

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe the main issue here is that `div` elements do not have a `name` attribute by default (see [Global attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Global_attributes)). If you were to perform your original JavaScript code on `input` elements, it would likely work because `input` elements have `name` attributes.

jQuery's [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method is able to parse even non-standard attributes ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/vF7cb/)).

jQuery's [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method is mostly used for properties such as `checked` and `disabled`, so using `.attr()` is probably the best course of action in any case.

Answer (score 5):

Input elements, for example, have the name property. `div`s do not have a *property* of `name` because that is not an inherent property of a `div`. I threw a fiddle together to explain the difference. http://jsfiddle.net/c7qDC/

When you add a `name="foo1"`, it sets an additional attribute to the element. Whereas, an `input` has an inherent *property* named `name`.

[See the documentation on input elements for the **properties** that they have](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLInputElement).

and compare that with the [documentation for a div](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLDivElement).

I'm sorry for emphasizing "property" so much. I'm just trying to make a point of the difference between a property and an attribute. You can set additional *attributes* on elements, whereas *properties* are inherent of the element type.